# ¿porque al subir mi pagina a github pages el background se pone gris?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

Tengo un mismo proyecto y si corro npm start todo esta bien y el fondo es blanco como deberia ser pero cuando corro npm run deploy para subirla a gh-pages el fondo de la pagina se pone gris, no cambie nada en los estilos y es el mismo proyecto aqui les dejo las fotos para comparar una es de fondo blanco y la otra gris.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿que me recomiendan que haga?, ¿que mejor intente subirla a netlify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando [tu código fuente](https://github.com/Ceci007/vidly-frontend/blob/master/src/App.js#L11..L12), estás importando antes la definición tus css (donde supongo está tu fondo blanco) que las librerías de material-kit, lo cual eventualmente sobreescribe la que pusiste tu:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cambia el orden en el cual estás cargando tus css de material y los personalizados, en general los tuyos siempre deberían estar al último. En el peor de los casos, si aún no te resulta, podrías usar `!important` para hacer un override de los estilos ya definidos:

```
body {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

Comment: si tienes razon debe ser eso pero tengo otro problema ahora cambie el logo y le puse `!important` al fondo blanco y elimine el fondo gris del material-kit pero me di cuenta que mi `npm run deploy` no esta actualizando los estilos puesto que no cargo el logo ni el fondo, ¿a que se debe esto?

Comment: Si funciono gracias corri el `npm run deploy` nuevamente y si lo agarro gracias de verdad, ya quedo jaja, va a ser uno de mis proyectos para mi portfolio, estoy feliz!! :D

Comment: @CeciBenitez en teoría, no deberías modificar directamente material-kit o cualquier otra librería externa. Lo normal es que reemplaces los estilos en un archivo aparte. El día que llegues a actualizar la librería, perderías todos los cambios que hayas hecho dentro de la librería.

Comment: esta bien tengo una copia, pero si tienes razon no deberia modificarlo solo le quite las partes que usan jQuery porque yo uso React y no quiero mesclar.